# Font Size WPF program source

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with `WPF`. I need WPF only for changing `font size`. So, I want to make something like `text editor` but only with changing the Font Size. I need to have **text box/ text block and a button ("Font Size")** which when you click it opens a new textbox and you add the desire size of the text. After you add the number it binds it and applies it to the text.

I can not write the code and will be very grateful if someone helps me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

```
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
```

/Style>

and then add the dynamic change :

Say, textbox1 is the textbox where you want to add size value..

TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Text="Sample text" FontSize="{Binding TextSize}" />

or

Application.Current.MainWindow.FontSize = Textbox1.text.toInt32();